# How to calculate Riemann and Ricci tensors for a sphere?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, curvature, metric-tensor

Let's have the metric for a sphere:
$$
dl^{2} = R^{2}\left(d\psi ^{2} + sin^{2}(\psi )(d \theta ^{2} + sin^{2}(\theta ) d \varphi^{2})\right).
$$
I tried to calculate Riemann or Ricci tensor's components, but I got problems with it.

The Ricci curvature must be
$$
R_{ij}=\frac{2}{R^{2}}g_{ij}.
$$
But when I use definition of Ricci tensor, I can't turn the expression into the expression for the metric tensor

Maybe, there are siome hints, which can help?

Comment: What problems are you having exactly? It will make a much better question if you show what you've tried and ask about the specific concept that is giving you trouble (and I'll be happy to reopen this as soon as you edit accordingly).

Comment: Ok. 

The Ricci curvature must be 

$R_{ij} = \frac{2}{R^{2}}g_{ij}$.

But when I use definition of Ricci tensor, I can't turn the expression into the expression for the metric tensor.

Comment: Oh, I meant edit it into the question

Comment: Maybe this would be better on the Math SE.

Comment: Isn't the last term in the bracket wrong? Shouldn't it be $sin^{2}(\psi ) sin^{2}(\theta ) d \varphi^{2}$?.

Comment: Your expression is equivalent to my expression.

Comment: The first time the Ricci tensor must be calculated without math packets.

Comment: David Zaslavsky, why didn't you reopen my question?

Comment: I'm not sure, can't you just read off the $g_{ij}$, since the differentials are not mixed? For example $g_{\theta\theta} =  R^2 \sin^2 \varphi$. I forgot why one is allowed to do that though...

Comment: But $g_{\varphi \varphi} = -R^{2}sin^{2}(\psi )sin^{2}(\theta )$.

Comment: @PhysiXxx I don't think I noticed that this was edited, but anyway: while the edit is, strictly speaking, an improvement, the question still isn't really asking anything specific. I'm not clear on what you mean by "turn the expression into the expression for the metric tensor," or more importantly, what conceptual problem you have when you try to do it. If you'd still like the question reopened, could you elaborate on that i.e. show a bit more of your work including the specific step that you're stuck on?