# Evaluating the Ricci tensor effectively

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

If given a metric of the form $$ds^2=\alpha^2(dr^2+r^2d\theta^2)$$ where $\alpha=\alpha(r)$, then can one immediately conclude that $$R_{\theta\theta}=r^2R_{rr}$$ where $R_{ab}$ is the [Ricci tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature), without doing any explicit calculations? I can show that this is true by the long-winded way of computing both explicitly, but it would seem that there may be a more elegant way?

Comment: More on evaluating Ricci tensor: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62907/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic: Thanks for the link :) However, I'm afraid I still haven't been able to see if the above mentioned is possible...

Comment: Apart from the sufficient answer by Qmechanic, this calculation isn't long-winded at all. The Riemann tensor only has 1 independent component in 2d!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what OP exactly is requesting, but OP's equation follows e.g. from the general [fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Special_cases) that for an arbitrary 2D surface, the Ricci tensor

$$ R_{\mu\nu} ~\propto~g_{\mu\nu} $$

is always proportional to the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$. This is basically a consequence of that in 2D the [Riemann curvature tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor) is complete determined by the scalar curvature.

Comment: Sorry for the novice and off-topic question, but what `OP` exactly stands for? I'm not familiar with this abbreviature yet.

Comment: OP=Original Poster, in this case [val](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/24336/val).